# Getting empty response in HTTP get request in QT QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, http

I am doing a simple HTTP get request to `www.google.co.in` but I am getting empty string in response.

Here is my code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager * mgr = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(mgr,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(onfinish(QNetworkReply*)));

    QUrl url("www.google.co.in");
    url.setScheme("http");
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/json");
    mgr->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("www.google.co.in")));


}

void MainWindow::onfinish(QNetworkReply *rep)
{
    QByteArray bts = rep->readAll();
    QString str(bts);
    qDebug() << str;

}

Output is :""
```

Facing same issue when doing post request to my own server.

In pro file I have done `QT       += core gui network`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the correct URL, in addition it is recommended that you use the new connection between signals and slots, and finally you must remove the `QNetworkReply`:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QUrl url("https://www.google.co.in/");
    QNetworkAccessManager *mgr = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(mgr,&QNetworkAccessManager::finished,this,&MainWindow::onfinish);
    mgr->get(QNetworkRequest(url));

}

void MainWindow::onfinish(QNetworkReply *rep)
{
    QByteArray bts = rep->readAll();
    QString str(bts);
    qDebug() << str;
    rep->deleteLater();
}
```